# Is there a way to easily set the icon a folder uses?

Tags: windows, automation, icons

I want to have certain folders show a picture I made my own instead of having to use the properties and specifying an `*.ico` file. Is there a way to use a `*.jpg` or `*.png` or `*.gif` or something like that instead? Or a program / script that allows me to more easily tell that folder to use an image I have.

I don't want to manually convert them because that's tedious to do. I'm planning to do this quite often, as a form of recognition when navigating my folder structure. *No, search is not an alternative solution...*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, for an icon on Windows you *must* use an `.ico` file. Although in Win9x days one could get away by using a renamed `.bmp`, but they look just terrible next to fancy Aero icons – especially since a typical ICO contains several image sizes with transparency layers.

You can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) to convert a PNG image to an ICO file:

```
convert foo.png foo.ico
```

or if you have PNGs of several sizes,

```
convert foo-*.png foo.ico
```

---

The other part, making Windows *use* your icon, is easier:

1. Create a [`desktop.ini`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini?redirectedfrom=MSDN) file in your directory, with the following contents:

   ```
   [.ShellClassInfo]
   IconFile=folder.ico
   IconIndex=0
   ```

   Relative paths for `IconFile` *should* be supported; they will also work over the network.

   See [this MSDN article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for detailed instructions on setting the folder icon programmatically.
2. Mark the directory as either "Read-only" (preferred) or "System":

   ```
   attrib +r Music
   ```

   Without this, Explorer won't even look for `desktop.ini` customizations, for performance reasons (as explained in [The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/2003/09/30)).
3. Optionally mark `desktop.ini` as hidden, so that it won't clutter the file list:

   ```
   attrib +h +s desktop.ini
   ```

Comment: What is step 2 used for?

Comment: @TomWijsman: Step 2 is required to tell Windows to actually look for a `desktop.ini` file – this is a performance optimization ([Old New Thing post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/30/55100.aspx)). Step 3 is optional – I personally just don't like seeing the `desktop.ini` files scattered everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for a more accurate answer, as well as a tool that supports multiple file types. :)

Comment: @StevenPenny: `+s` has some other side effects, so it's only recommended for real system files/folders.

Comment: @grawity what I am saying is that `attrib +r Music` **does not work** on my system, only `attrib +s Music`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, .ICO files are used (exclusively) for the Icons of folders (since, well, they're Icons ;) ).

You're best/only bet is to convert the image file(s) to the .ICO format.

Perhaps check out these for some ideas/utilities to make the conversion easier on you:

- [How do I convert a .PNG into a .ICO?](https://superuser.com/questions/227736/how-do-i-convert-a-png-into-a-ico)
- https://superuser.com/questions/147056/what-tool-can-i-use-to-convert-various-formats-into-icon-files
- [Batch convert SVG images to desired size PNG or ICO](https://superuser.com/questions/260047/batch-convert-svg-images-to-desired-size-png-or-ico)

Personally I like [Axialis' IconWorkshop](http://axialis.com/iconworkshop/) for all my .ICO needs. :)

As for injecting/assigning them without using the Properties, that's a different story, and actually pretty easy.

You can specify it by creating/modifying the `desktop.ini` (text) file in the folder you wish to apply the icon to.  *Note*: this file is a 'hidden' and 'system' file.

Example desktop.ini:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\Users\techie007\Documents\myNukeBall.ico,0
```

Comment: There is a web service [png2ico](http://www.pngtoico.com/). No any installation is required.

Comment: This sounds easy to automate with a command-line png2iso (adding that to a right click menu for ease) as well as well as making a file with `.\folder.ico` instead which I can easy copy / paste and then I make both files hidden. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub Change_Folder_Icon()

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim folderPath As String, DesktopIni As String

folderPath = "C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\my_folder"

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
DesktopIni = folderPath & "Desktop.ini"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With FSO
    .GetFolder(folderPath).Attributes = System
    
    If .FileExists(DesktopIni) Then .DeleteFile DesktopIni
    
    With .CreateTextFile(DesktopIni, True)
        .WriteLine "[.ShellClassInfo]"
        ' Windows 10 Icons
        '.WriteLine "IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll"
        '.WriteLine "IconIndex=12"
        
        ' Custom icon
        .WriteLine "IconFile=C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\my_folder\Icon.ico"
        .WriteLine "IconIndex=0"
        .Close
    End With
    
    .GetFile(DesktopIni).Attributes = Hidden
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Might be useful to explain what this does and how to run it rather than just giving a block of vbscript. A more useful script would be one that you right-click on an icon, select "use icon for parent folder" and then it creates the correct ini file and hides both the icon and the ini file.

Comment: How is this better than the manual methods described in the other answers? Please include reasons to use this as well as some idea of when a macro is appropriate.